# What is the proper way to build a web app that deals with multiple interfaces?

Tags: php, web, interface

I am using PHP for a year now. I used to build my website using a way that i think it will not be suitable for an application that has multiple interfaces (web, Android, IOS..). I simply create an html page or a form and then handle the inputs in PHP script. This is a simple example of a login script:

This is the login form:

```
<?php
 $error = '';
 if(isset($_GET['error']))
     $error = $_GET['error'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Blogmaker Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class="container">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BlogMaker</a>
            </div>
            <br><br>
          </nav>
          <!-- Static navbar -->


          <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                  <h1>BlogMaker</h1>
                  <p>You want to create your blog for free! You can do it right now. 
                      Just click in the "Create My Blog" button below and start posting and receiving comments
                      from other peoples.
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="Signup.php" role="button">Create My Blog</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <?php
                    if($error=='')
                        echo'<br><br>';
                    else
                        echo'<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error.'</div>';
                  ?>
                    <form class="form-signin" action="login.php">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus name="username">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required name="pw">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    </form>

              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="footer">
                    <p>&copy; BlogMaker 2013</p>
              </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the login process handled in a PHP script:

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once 'DATABASE-CONFIG.php';
$username='';
$pw='';
if(isset($_GET['username'])&&isset($_GET['pw'])){
    $username=$_GET['username'];
    $pw=$_GET['pw'];
    mysql_connect(SERVERNAME,DBUSERNAME,DBPASSWD) or die('Fail to connect to DB server');
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME)or die('Fail to find the DB in the server');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header('Location:myblog.php');
    }
    else
        header('Location:index.php?error=Please check your username and your password!');
}else
    header('Location:index.php?error=Username and password are mandatory!');

?>
```

As you see, i call the html input fields by name and check user input. I believe this is a bad practice to build a website. So my question is what is the best practice to create a web application in PHP that deals with several interfaces? i just want the main concept. Also it would be very good with a small example.

Thanks

Comment: Just for your information: you're vulnerable to XSS atacks, so you pass `$error` by `$_GET` and then `echo` it in your page without escape it, you should use:
`echo htmlspecialchars($error);`
You should use this because user can pass whatever he want by url.

Comment: Pages would also load faster if you kept the jquery files on your server rather than linking to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js` I think. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you guys. I should've written this in the question but i'm aware of what you're telling me. I tried to make the code as simple as possible to make the question clear. If you have an answer please help. Thank you again  .

Answer (score 1):

I would look into building a RESTful API. This way you can write all of your business logic once and make several clients interact with it (website, mobile apps, etc. Here is a good place to get started: [API tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MVC design pattern (Model - View - Controller). This will make it easy to decouple business logic from your presentation code by feeding different views to the different platforms you wish to support.

Most modern PHP web frameworks use the MVC architecture. [Laravel](http://laravel.com), [Fuel](http://fuelphp.com), etc...

[Wikipedia on MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
[MVC Tutorial for beginners](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488)

Comment: Yeah that would be good but i was trying to avoid OO :( .. anyway laravel looks good. I'll consider using it. Thanks.